# How to make valgrind to exactly reproduce bug?

Tags: c, valgrind

I created a c program which crashes (segmentation fault). I want to find the error using valgrind, but when I run it:

```
valgrind -v ./executable
```

the program don't crash. It still crashes when I run it using gdb.

How can I set up valgrind to reproduce the bug, like gdb?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug

Comment: @ouah, so it is impossible?

Comment: You can probably find the error in gdb.

Comment: If your bug is a race condition/timing-dependent, valgrind might slow down things so much that the bug isn't triggered anymore. Can you reproduce it 100% without valgrind?

Comment: Yes. I even tested on other machine. So frustrating.

Comment: How much of the C standard library (or other libraries) does your program use?

Comment: does valgrind report any errors?

Comment: Using gdb, I found that it crashes somewhere in malloc.c, on a free call. Valgrind report errors like "invalid read of size" on 3 free calls and, what's intersting, a "conditional jump or move depends on uninialized value" on a printf statement, which I doubt it is the problem.

Comment: First make sure all valgrind warnings/errors are cleared

Comment: @perreal, what do you mean by cleaning them?

Comment: fix the issues so there are no invalid reads or jumps that depend on uninitialized values

Comment: @perreal, that is what I'm trying to do, but it is not trivial.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky A hint: identify what `free` call causes the crash. Then check the argument of `malloc` when you allocate memory for this object (i.e., are you allocating enough bytes?). Then check all the accesses to this object and look for a buffer overflow when writing to this specific object (i.e., is a write accessing an element outside of the array object?).

Comment: I managed to find the bug (a stupid one, as always), I keeped the length of vector in [0] position, when I was freeing it (in a for), I was freeing the [0] position first, losing the length and corrupting the for. But, the question remains, how to make valgrind reproduce the bug, like gdb does?

Comment: @gg.kaspersky, even if it could reproduce the bug, you would still need to track it down. IMO, it is no better than invalid read/write error reports

Comment: It is probably because valgrind "keeps" memory around after you've freed it, and valgrind didn't (for some reason) spot that you were using it after freeing it (maybe because you only read from it?)

Comment: You could try using [electric fence](http://linux.die.net/man/3/efence) which arranges to place your allocations at the edges of accessible memory so that anything which overruns a buffer causes an immediate segfault so you can see where it happened. It will also make freed memory inaccessible so you can tell if your application uses a freed buffer. It's not as comprehensive in some ways as valgrind, but I find it easier to have a crash triggered immediately rather than be told afterwards, and also electric fence is faster. It's also really easy: just link with `-lefence`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I set up valgrind to reproduce the bug, like gdb?

You should not and in fact you can't.

This is because program runs under Valgrind in environment slightly different from when it runs natively. This is how Valgrind works, see [Valgrind FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html#faq.crashes).

What you really need is to fix all Valgrind errors, especially invalid reads.